# Routing with only {id} parameter returns "resource cannot be found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to setup routing as follows.

Right now My URL looks like *www.mysite.com/Products/index/123*

My goal is to setup URL like *www.mysite.com/123*

Where: *Products* is my controller name , *index* is my action name and *123* is *nullable* `id` parameter.

This is my route :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {         
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
          "OnlyId",
          "{id}",
      new { controller = "Products", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

     );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );


    }
```

and this is my Action Method

```
public ActionResult index (WrappedViewModels model,int? id)
    {

        model.ProductViewModel = db.ProductViewModels.Find(id);
        model.ProductImagesViewModels = db.ProductImagesViewModels.ToList();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

this is my model wrapper :

```
 public class WrappedViewModels
{          
    public ProductViewModel ProductViewModel { get; set; }               
    public ProductImagesViewModel ProductImagesViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImagesViewModel> ProductImagesViewModels { get; set; 
}
```

Error is thrown on this URL : www.mysite.com/123

**The question is:**
Why my view returns this error and how to avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your `WrappedViewModels` definition looks like ? This should work fine. What is the url you are trying which is giving you 404 ?

Comment: Hi. I've edited my question , error occurs on this URL "www.mysite.com/123"

Comment: You need to include all your routes because order matters.

Comment: That route must be first, but it also means that most of your other urls would ever work (you would need a route constraint). You need to show all your route definitions

Comment: I've updated my question with requested informations , hope it helps.

Comment: Navigating to `www.mysite.com/123` will not throw that error based on the code you shown (but as I noted earlier, your other routes would not work correctly without adding a constraint to ensure `id` is an `int`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RegisterRoutes you need to specify little bit more.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "OnlyId",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "index" },
    constraints: new{ id=".+"});
```

and then you need to specify the routing of each anchor tag as

```
@Html.RouteLink("123", routeName: "OnlyId", routeValues: new { controller = "Products", action = "index", id= "id" })
```

I think this will resolve you immediate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that `id` parameter is nullable integer value, place a route constraint with `\d` regex like this, so that it not affect other routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "OnlyId",
     url: "{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "index" }, // note that this default doesn't include 'id' parameter
     constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

If you're not satisfied for standard parameter constraints, you can create a class which inheriting `IRouteConstraint` and apply that on your custom route as in this example:

```
// adapted from /a/11911917/
public class CustomRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public CustomRouteConstraint(Regex regex)
    {
        this.Regex = regex;
    }

    public CustomRouteConstraint(string pattern) : this(new Regex("^(" + pattern + ")$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
    {
    }

    public Regex Regex { get; set; }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest && parameterName == "id")
        {
            if (values["id"] == UrlParameter.Optional)
                 return true;
            if (this.Regex.IsMatch(values["id"].ToString()))
                 return true;

            // checking if 'id' parameter is exactly valid integer
            int id;
            if (int.TryParse(values["id"].ToString(), out id))
                 return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then place custom route constraint on `id`-based route to let other routes work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "OnlyId",
     url: "{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     constraints: new CustomRouteConstraint(@"\d*")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed Routing order. So create first route definition which handles all available controllers and then define one which will handle the rest of the requests, say, one that handles the `www.mysite.com/{id}` kind of requests.

So **swap** the *OnlyId* and *Default* rules and No more changes required. I believe It should work fine now.